MATLAB's filterDesigner "generate C header" function generating a lot of "0" coefficients when "exports as 32bit unsigned" is selected
As stated on the title, it looks like the 32b unsigned filter coefficients generated by filterDesigner is not correct:

The same filter when "exports as 32bit signed" is selected:

I do not know how the coefficients are generated but the unsigned one with zeroes does not work properly when used in my project.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Command and parameters used to generate the filter:
Fs(Sampling frequency): 4460Hz
Fp(Cutoff frequency): 1000Hz
Rp:  5.7565e-04
Rst  1e-4

eqnum = firceqrip(N,Fp/(Fs/2),[Rp Rst],'passedge');
dfilt.dffir(eqnum)
filterDesigner
... and then generate the C header from there


What else would you expect to happen if you convert a negative number to an unsigned ? Some of the original coefficients are negative and when you convert them to unsigned the get zero'd.

Take this answer as a starting point to understand how to achieve what you want.
